# Probability of at least one hunter question

Tags: probability

> The probability that a randomly chosen Nova Scotian male hunts is $.3$, and the probability that they drive an all terrain vehicle (ATV) is $.4$. The probability that they do both is $.2$.
>
> Suppose you choose 3 Nova Scotian men at random. What is the probability that at least one hunts?

I got an answer of $.875$.

$P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \wedge B) - P(B \wedge C) - P (A \wedge B \wedge C)$

is this right or did I do this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

what is the probability none of them hunts?

> $\frac{7}{10}\cdot\frac{7}{10}\frac{7}{10}=.343$ So the probability at least one of them hunts is $1-.343=.657$

Comment: Shouldn't it be 5/10 instead of 7/10 because if they hunt or do both, it still counts as hunting right?

Answer (score 0):

Thread necromancy time. Lightly edited:

> I got an answer of $0.875$:
>
> $$ P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \wedge B) - P(B \wedge C) - P(A \wedge B \wedge C) $$
>
> Is this right or did I do this wrong?

It's not right. I get the impression that this was an attempt at the inclusion-exclusion principle, but it is not being applied correctly. And anyway, it is not needed here.

There is only $A =$ "hunts" and $B =$ "drives an ATV", where $P(A) = 0.3$ and $P(B) = 0.4$. We do not represent the conjunction of the two, with probability $0.2$, as a third event $C$; we just write $A \wedge B$, and then we could have written

$$
P(A \vee B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \wedge B)
$$

allowing us to determine that $P(A \vee B) = 0.5$.

However, this is not necessary. The question only asks us to determine the probability that at least one out of three Nova Scotian men hunts. For that, we only need $P(A) = 0.3$. The probability that a given Nova Scotian man doesn't hunt is $1-P(A) = 0.7$, so the probability that *none* of the three hunts is $[1-P(A)]^3 = 0.7^3 = 0.343$ (assuming hunting is independent across the men), and the probability that at least one of them hunts is $1$ minus that, or

$$
P(\text{at least one of three Nova Scotian men hunts}) = 1-0.7^3 = 0.657
$$